# xfce keyboard options/which ubuntu version

Tags: keyboard, xfce

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this.

I just got an xfce desktop running on an HP chomebook, running via crouton.  I believe it's a version of Ubuntu.

The only keyboard option is the US English one.  I'm hoping a simple matter of putting a file somewhere will allow a UK English configuration.

One of the solutions above refers to /etc/xrdp/... but I don't even have the directory /etc/xrdp, so I'm doubting that will work for me.

Any help?

Comment: Hello! You can check which Ubuntu version you have by doing `cat /etc/os-release` -- please edit your question to add that information, then it may be easier for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

This:
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Keyboard#non-us-layout
gives a description of how it's done.